# Using more than one reporter in NLDoReport[] (running NetLogo simulations from Mathematica)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, netlogo, reporters

I am running NetLogo simulations from Mathematica.

I need to run a simulation and store the values of 2 attributes in each tick during this simulation.

By running the command below, I could get a Mathematica list with the values of a **single attribute** (house_price of location 1):

NLDoReport["go", **"[house_price] of location 1"**, 200]

However, I do not know how to do the same thing for **more than one attribute**. I tried to pass a list o reporters, as below, but it did not work.

NLDoReport["go", **{"[house_price] of location 1", "[population] of location 1"}**, 200]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So your syntax is NLDoReport["go", reporter, count]. I think if you define a reporter routine in Netlogo that combines the data you need into a list, and call that reporter, it should work. ( I don't have mathematica to try this out.)  Something like this ( or similar with whatever syntax works in NetLogo to return your desired list ).

In NetLogo:

```
to-report mydata
 let mylist list [house-price] of location 1 [population] of location 1
 report mylist
end
```

in Mathematica:

```
 NLDoReport["go", mydata, 200]
```